# addClass() function doesn't work after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple AJAX call that it is getting trigger after someone clicks an anchor. After the AJAX is successful I would like to add a class at the anchor that triggered the AJAX.

Although the script is working fine, and the success function returns all the correct data, when I try to `addClass()` it doesn't work. I used a `hide()` method to see if jQuery runs correctly and it doesn't work either. The console doesn't print any errors.

For debugging I used an alert and it works! How can the alert work fine and both `addClass()` and `hide()` not?

```
<a href="#" class="refreshor" value="20">1</a>
<a href="#" class="refreshor" value="40">2</a>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.refreshor').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var search = $('#searchin').val();
        var page = $(this).text();
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "components/com_tagger/scripts/ajaxSearch.php",
            data: {
                "search": search,
                "page": page
            },
            success:function(response) {
                $('.ajaxSearchResults').html(response);
                $(that).addClass('preventer'); //this doesnt work
                $(that).hide(); //this doesnt work
                var test = $(that).text(); 
                alert(test); //this works!                  
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: are the links inside `.ajaxSearchResults` ?

Comment: yes they are  inside

Comment: @sin, so the link bound to `that` is not part of the DOM anymore by the time you `addClass()` and `hide()` it. It was replaced by another link from the markup in the response.

Comment: So the clicked link is overwritten with `response`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the success callback you replace the content of `.ajaxSearchResults`

```
$('.ajaxSearchResults').html(response);
```

Then `that` is not referring to the ones that are inside this container.

You need to use delegate, that will allow you to bind events on elements that not yet in the DOM

```
$('.ajaxSearchResults').on('click', '.refreshor',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = $('#searchin').val();
    var page = $(this).text();

    var thisValue = $(this).attr('value'); // save the current value of the `a` clicked
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "components/com_tagger/scripts/ajaxSearch.php",
        data: {
            "search": search,
            "page": page
        },
        success:function(response) {
            $('.ajaxSearchResults').html(response);

            var that = $('.ajaxSearchResults').find('.refreshor[value="'+thisValue+'"]'); 
            // look for the `a` that have the saved value.

            that.addClass('preventer');
            that.hide(); 
            var test = that.text(); 
            alert(test);        
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Alas, `$('.refreshor')` will match both links, not only the one that was bound to `that`. No easy solution to track it without changing the markup (e.g. adding `id` attributes) I'm afraid.

Comment: `$('.refreshor')` will add the class on all anchors. i would like to add it only on the one it triggered the ajax

Comment: @sin So use a variable to reference clicked anchor value attribute to filter it out

Answer (score 4):

You have stated (in comments) that the links you have (for which you're trying to add a class) a reference for are inside the panel where you are replacing the entire content.

By replacing the content, the reference you have to the links are no longer in the DOM. You will need to have some way of identifying which link was pressed, and find that link again in the replaced markup.

One suggestion would be to identify the links using `data-*` attributes (`value` is not a valid property of an `a` element)

```
<a href="#" class="refreshor" data-value="20">1</a>
<a href="#" class="refreshor" data-value="40">2</a>
```

And on click capture that value:

```
$('.refreshor').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = $('#searchin').val();
    var page = $(this).text();
    var val = $(this).data('value');
    ....
```

When you replace the content, you could then find this link:

```
success:function(response) {
     $('.ajaxSearchResults').html(response);
     $('.refreshor').filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('value') == val;
     }).addClass('preventor');
     ...
```

Comment: because i reprint them in the ajaxfile

Comment: You have to rebind the click event on the new elements then

Comment: @Hacketo - yes, you probably do. That's outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: @Jamiec as expert, you should at least tell newbie OP that the code you share will not work (that will save some time for OP)

Comment: @Hacketo - as should you re: the use of invalid properties on an element. Nobody's perfect ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are replacing the anchors and you want to set the same one later, save its value to a variable and look it up after you replace it all in the success:-

Note `a` does not have a `value` so use `data-value="20"` instead.

html

```
<a href="#" class="refreshor" data-value="20">1</a>
<a href="#" class="refreshor" data-value="40">2</a>
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.refreshor', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var search = $('#searchin').val();
        var page = $(this).text();
        var that = this;
        var value = $(this).data('value');
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "components/com_tagger/scripts/ajaxSearch.php",
            data: {
                "search": search,
                "page": page
            },
            success:function(response) {
                $('.ajaxSearchResults').html(response);

                $('.refreshor[data-value="' + value + '"]').addClass('preventer');
                $('.refreshor[data-value="' + value + '"]').hide();

                var test = $(that).text(); 
                alert(test); //this works!                  
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

And use event delegation to bind the click so the event is not lost.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and answers i came up to this that works fine:

I added id attributes to anchors

```
  <a href="#" id="link1" class="refreshor" >1</a>
  <a href="#" id="link2" class="refreshor" >2</a>
```

And changed the js to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.refreshor').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var search = $('#searchin').val();
        var page = $(this).text();
        var that = '#link'+ page;

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "components/com_tagger/scripts/ajaxSearch.php",
            data: {"search":search,"page":page},
            success:function(response) {
                $('.ajaxSearchResults').html(response);
                $(that).addClass('preventer');


            } 
        });


    });

});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to add it after ajax triggers.

```
<a href="#" class="refreshor" value="20">1</a>
<a href="#" class="refreshor" value="40">2</a>




jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.refreshor', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var search = $('#searchin').val();
     var page = $(this).text();
     var that = this;
     $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "components/com_tagger/scripts/ajaxSearch.php",
        data: {
            "search": search,
            "page": page
     },
     success:function(response) {
       $('.ajaxSearchResults').html(response);
       $(that).hide(); //this doesnt work
       var test = $(that).text(); 
       alert(test); //this works!                  
     }

     $(that).addClass('preventer'); //check it out

   });
 });
});
```